# Accessing javascript object with mixed key square brackets

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to access elements of a javascript object. I have no control over how it has been created.

An example is as follows:

```
parameters = Object { checkout_method="guest",  billing[firstname]="fasfdas",  billing[lastname]="fdsa" }
```

this works fine -

```
var checkout = parameters.checkout_method;
```

however trying to access any of the billing ones results in either an error or an 'undefined'

```
var billing = parameters.billing['firstname'];
var billing = parameters['billing.firstname'];
```

basically I've crawled stackoverflow and tried about 20 different combinations to get the values with no result.

Does anyone have any idea how you access an object key with mixed square bracketed content?

Comment: Does parameters['billing[firstname]'] return the correct result?

Comment: `var billing = parameters["billing[firstname]"];`

Comment: please add valid javascript code for `parameters`.

Comment: How about [this](http://jsbin.com/jatuki/edit?js,console)?

Comment: As other have suggested.. does `parameters["billing[firstname]"];` work?

Comment: How are you making this object?  You shouldn't be naming keys `billing[firstname]`, it makes it hard to access (as you can see).

Comment: @RocketHazmat Op said he has no control over how it's been created

Comment: @RajshekarReddy: Whoops, guess I missed that part in the question :-P

Comment: @RocketHazmat - as mentioned I have no control over it's creation

Comment: @JordanBurnett - thanks that works!

Comment: and also the others suggesting that

Comment: Is the object you presented the actual textual content of the object coming from the server? In this case, you have quite a bit of work ahead of yourself to parse this special format. Or is it some sort of representation of an actual JS object that you are just presenting this way for purposes of this question, and is actually something like `{checkout_method: guest",  billing: {firstname: "fasfdas", lastname: "fdsa"}}`? In that case, your proposal of `parameters.billing['firstname'];` should work just fine.

Comment: Or do you have an actual JS object with keys such as `billing[firstname]`? If that is really the case, then of course `parameters['billing[filrstname]']` will work, as other commenters have suggested.

Comment: @kieron Great - I've added it as an answer below if you're happy with the solution.

Comment: "that works fine" no it doesn't, that's not valid JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Confusingly, the object you have contains key names that contain square brackets.

Access them with

```
var billing = parameters['billing[firstname]'];
```

Comment: Ya that might be it. It is weird the object. Using the brackets with it inside the quotes might be correct.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try this?

billing = parameters.billing.firstname;

Or

billing = parameters.billing.firstname?

They are sending you a weird object.

Comment: He said he tried `parameters.billing['firstname']`, which is the same as what you suggest.